# Route traffic through google servers or google proxy

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome, proxy, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux on a 384kbps internet. But when I download from google server eg. from google drive or gmail, I get download speeds upto 3mbps. Our ISP has allowed unlimited bandwidth only for google servers.

In google chrome there is an extension data compression proxy, when installed I get browsing and downloading speeds upto 3mbps only in chrome.

I want to apply the same proxy system wide for eg. in terminal.

Currently apt-get update takes forever.

So is it possible to route traffic through google servers or can I download Kali packages through chrome

Answer (score 0):

I never tried, <strike>I don't even know if they offer that</strike> but you could rent a Google Cloud VPS and build a VPN : https://cloud.google.com/

**EDIT:**
Found this about Google VPS: https://serverfault.com/questions/416557/does-google-provide-hosting-servers-means-like-vps-or-dedicated-servers

Build OpenVPN server : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server/